# No output sound using fluidsynth + soundfont-fluid with midi2video

Tags: python, linux, audio, video, midi

I am trying to use [midi2video](https://github.com/mobeets/midi2video) to get a video and audio file from a midi file, but eventhough I get both outputs, the .mp3 or .wav file has no sound (I checked the speakers in my laptop are working).
[image: Resulting video + audio (which is non-existent). Filename: example.mid.mp4.]

I tried placing the FluidR3_GM.sf2 file in different directories, but it does not seem to affect. Everyting seems to be right in my conf file. I changed nothing from the python file.

I am using Linux and my Python version is 3.11. Also, the editor I am using is vscode.

```
[video]
; resolution [pixel]
width = 800
height = 100

frameRate = 25

; fadeIn & fadeOut decreases performance as there are less reusable frames
; fadeIn effect is a slightly darker color at note hit
noteFadeIn = 0
; fadeOut might be useful for very short notes that are difficult to see
noteFadeOut = 0

; add audio requires fluidsynth and a soundfont-file (e.g. soundfont-fluid)
addAudio = 1
soundFont = /home/amapy/Documents/Spring_2024/ADLCV/Project/midi2video-master/FluidR3_GM/FluidR3_GM.sf2


[piano]

; use any of the noteNumbers [0-127] as startNote/endNote
; "auto" will use the lowest/highest note of the midi file as first/last key
; black key boundries gets extended to next white key
;-----------------------------------------------------------
;                      note numbers
; octave |  C   C#  D   D#  E   F   F#  G   G#  A   A#  B
;-----------------------------------------------------------
;   -2   |  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
;   -1   |  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
;    0   |  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35
;    1   |  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47
;    2   |  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
;    3   |  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71
;    4   |  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83
;    5   |  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95
;    6   |  96  97  98  99  100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107
;    7   |  108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119
;    8   |  120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127
startNote = auto
endNote = auto


colorWhiteKeys = #FFFFFF
colorBlackKeys = #131313
colorHighlight = #DE4439
outlineColorWhiteKeys = #131313
outlineColorBlackKeys = #131313
outlineColorHighlight = #6e160f

[preprocess]
; in case the .mid file is created via https://github.com/Pomax/arduino-midi-recorder
; or one of its forks it may happen that it's necessary to fix the track length byte
; of the midi file.
; thanks to https://github.com/Pomax/arduino-midi-recorder/blob/master/fix.py
fixTrackLength = 0
```